# Script - Retrieve text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have several input in my html (this is one input for exemple) :

```
<TH>
    <FORM>
        <input name="designation" type="text" size="12" />
    </FORM>
</TH>
```

So, I want retrieve the text input and show it. So I use this script :

```
$("#Compil").click(function() {
    var n_input = document.getElementById("designation").value;
    alert('Designation : ' + n_input); // -> n_input non defini (undefined)
});
```

But don't work. My alert don't display. Can you help me please?

*PS : This a script in Javascript or jQuery please?*

Comment: have a `id='designation'` in html

Comment: You should use `getElementsByName()` instead `getElementById()`

Comment: **id** or **name** is better ? Or are they identic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the id attribute on your input, simply change your html to include

```
<input id="designation" name="designation" type="text" size="12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1)in you script you getting the value by id designation but you didn't add id attribute like designation in your html input field .so only its throwing undefined error.

```js
$("#Compil").click(function() {
    var n_input = document.getElementById("designation").value;
    alert('Designation : ' + n_input); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TH>
    <FORM>
        <input name="designation" id="designation" type="text" size="12" />
      
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Compil" value="submit" />
    </FORM>
</TH>
```